# Quote/QuoteItem addErrorInfo is not persistent

Tags: magento-1, quote, quoteitem

On Magento 1, I'm having an issue where the quote and quote item error messages is not persistent.

```
$item->addErrorInfo('cataloginventory', Mage_CatalogInventory_Helper_Data::ERROR_QTY, $message);
```

The above code is fine for set the status in that request. However, as soon as another request hit, the error message is not there any more e.g. `$quote->getErrors()` returns empty array.

I've tried to do `$quote->save()` as well as `$quoteItem->save()` but I don't think that's the reason.

Comment: I'm having this issue too (see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135268/quote-sethaserrorstrue-not-working). Nobody is helping. Is there a way to see this error through at least to the cart page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a break point in
Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item::removeErrorInfosByParams
and Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item::_clearErrorInfo
to check if there's any other observer method that reset the error info.

Answer (score 3):

Confirming addErrorInfo is only for a single request and not persist into session.

The way Magento core handle the cart error is upon cart update and re-check before checkout progress.